# react-native-apple-authentication decode with jwt-decode not working

Tags: ios, react-native, jwt

Following [react-native-apple-authentication](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication) I want to use jwt-decode on the `identityToken` returned by the apple login to catch informations like the email, following [jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode#polyfilling-atob).
So by using `import "core-js/stable/atob";` I realize I don't have the core-js folder in my node_modules so I leave `import "atob"` which I have, so with the following code:

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import "atob"
const signInAppleAuth = async () => {
    const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
        requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
        requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME, appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL],
    });
    const { identityToken } = appleAuthRequestResponse
    const decoded = jwtDecode(identityToken)
    console.log(" decoded: ", decoded);
}
```

It gives me this:

> InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: invalid json for part #2
> (JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string)

`appleAuthRequestResponse` look like:

> {"identityToken":
> "eyJraWQiOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoib3JnLnJlYWN0anMubmF0aXZlLmV4YW1wbGUuSGFwcHlTdW5ueUhvdXJGcm9udCIsImV4cCI6MTcwMjEyODEwNSwiaWF0IjoxNzAyMDQxNzA1LCJzdWIiOiIwMDAxOTUuZWQ1M2RjMTk1MDA1NDU2NTk5Yjk2YzMzMGY5ZmUwNTIuMTU1MyIsIm5vbmNlIjoiYWU1ZmIwY2Y4MWI1YzlhNjNiOWY2NmEzOWZkNjgxZmQzZmU2NWI4MDFmNjRiZTE0MTQ4OGY5NTRlMmM4MDc0OSIsImNfaGFzaCI6Iko0S3NGTV85c0NzbzBhS0p5aXhzRmciLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE3MDIwNDE3MDUsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.uCNoY1FfPwB4rry7-0yVsQapPWnmTEpqhcLpg81xoC5b3u6nGRfjWhMjJZK2_gfIeGqb1DR9-eVlzl5JVMOownVTEQljP1kSrfRQzyUhBRlI_cMa9xqfSf9SOoySg8YshgTZcdlV-M9HIJVHjQYHjwS2relaXd7whHy1ps5pOF2QjYsTaQfpFJgajGjSZXFzNEKTyCtoaDWrAq5zlqAInY7WoCbswSNcOctTwaiTnhi36faWaNC2RPV2jwiNqDT1mSZHqzxjDH2-C_c8o9EWdwq0ShWcc0ILBlFs0jzVAtNgcRc9626OdYzXblzORktXVi9-TY43XzGeGTY_fqfE6g"

And when I use the token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) it works well. Why ?

Note:I also don't have the `base-64` folder in my modules for this solution :

```
import { decode } from "base-64";
global.atob = decode;
```

Comment: Can you post the content of ```identityToken```?

Comment: I edited, But weirdly When I try it on jwt.io There is not even the email appearing in the returned decode ? :/
I think my only solution Is that I have to had infos at the first connexion time, then if the user reconnect, I will have to play with the user id with my data base... 
Apple makes me loose some hair